# How to make an MFC Dialog Based document where a button will execute 4 different texts in a 1 second difference (WM_TIMER)?

Tags: mfc

Can somebody help me? I want to know how to make an MFC Dialog Based document where a button will execute 4 different texts in a 1 second difference (WM_TIMER)?

Comment: Buttons do not execute text. Show your code instead of describing it.

Comment: THe question is too boroad and too unclear. [Edit] your question and be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Example like this..

```
void CMyDialog::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    SetTimer(123, 1000, NULL);
}

void CMyDialog::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    static int nCount = 0;
    nCount++;

    switch (nCount)
    {
    case 1: m_TestBtn.SetWindowText(_T("1.."));         break;
    case 2: m_TestBtn.SetWindowText(_T("2.."));         break;
    case 3: m_TestBtn.SetWindowText(_T("3.."));         break;
    case 4: m_TestBtn.SetWindowText(_T("! Hello !"));   break;
    default: nCount = 0; KillTimer(123);
    }

    CMyDialog::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```